# EF Code First Update Database Encountered Error "There is already an object named 'Products' in the database"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF5 Code First in MVC4. There are tables where fields have decimal datatypes. I just wanted to update the precision of decimal originally **from (18,2) to (18,4)**. Please help.

To achieve the goal I just modified the OnModelCreating something like this:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<DealerLevelDiscount>().Property(d =>d.Discount ).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<DealerTransaction>().Property(d => d.ProductDiscount).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<DealerTransaction>().Property(d => d.VolumeDiscount).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        }
```

Then I just ran:

**PM> update-database -verbose** command using Package Manager Console

But I got error:

**There is already an object named 'Products' in the database.**

**Code Generated by Migration**

```
PM> update-database -verbose
Using StartUp project 'SharkStore.WebUI'.
Using NuGet project 'SharkStore.Infrastructure'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'SharkStore' (DataSource: (local), Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying code-based migrations: [201304270821111_InitialCreate, 201305041132116_updateDatabae, 201305111219416_5112013, 201305141351533_5142013, 201305231451514_5232013, 201306130611074_06132013_updates, 201306221339425_06222013, 201306231051456_06232013, 201306251538120_06251013, 201306251611006_06262013_01, 201307021414262_07022013, 201307040902338_742013, 201307140659150_07142013, 201307140701597_07142013_1, 201308050843017_852013, 201309270307238_09272013].
Applying code-based migration: 201304270821111_InitialCreate.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Thumbnail] [nvarchar](max),
    [MainImage] [nvarchar](max),
    [FileData] [nvarchar](max),
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [ShortDescription] [nvarchar](max),
    [LongDescription] [nvarchar](max),
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DownloadCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BHMinVersion] [nvarchar](max),
    [BHMinEdition] [nvarchar](max),
    [TrialPeriod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime],
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

**Migration Table**

[image]

**Stacktrace**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Products' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
ClientConnectionId:bcd5bb53-2e1d-4121-8aae-4ebfe353ebf6
```

Comment: Post the code generated by this migration.  Also, what does the _MigrationHistory table look like?

Comment: @cadrell0 I just updated the question.

Comment: Well I see one major problem.  It is applying the migration `201304270821111_InitialCreate`.  This does not show in your _MigrationHistory table, but that does have a ...._InitialMigrations.  Did your migrations get renamed after creating this database?

Comment: What @cadrell0 said! If you renamed your migration, you may have to rebase your migrations, and just start from a brand new InitialCreate with your current database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and after trying to add new migrations and update the database schema with them, without success, I deleted all the migration source files and I deleted the migration entries rows found on the dbo_MigrationHistory table. After that I added a new migration and was able to update schema changes.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but the above answer did not solve my problem but manually dropping all the tables and then using `update-database -force`in the package manager console did the job for me......