# Getting error "There is already an object named 'abc' in the database." even after keeping the hibernate.ddl-auto value to update

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to boot up a spring boot application which connects to local ms-sqlserver (2019). I have already setup the db manually and kept the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update` but still when application starts up it tries to create the table and throw an error. Application started but there was exception in console:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'abc' in the database.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:868)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:768)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:744)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I am not able to understand when I have set the hibernate property to update why it's not able to detect the existing table "abc".

Can anyone point out if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Have you checked to have the correct default_schema property for Hibernate?

Comment: try adding ```;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS YOURSCHEMANAME``` behind your ```spring.datasource.url``` in the propertiesfile?

Comment: @Paul why it's required when we already have our auto-ddl=update. Can you please share some reference where this property is specified.

Comment: @Manish I'm right to assume you're using JPA-hibernate? Then this might include some basic information https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa . On the other hand, I'm starting to think that your manual setup doesn't match your Entity-classes

Comment: @Paul Yes I am using JPA-Hibernate. Also I understood that there may be some mismatch b/w existing table and Entity class but don't you think even in that case too "update" should not try to create the same table again. That's the error i am facing. Update should only add any additional changes if there is any in my Entity class instead of creating the table again.

Comment: @Manish As pointed out in this answer, I would also drop the tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542462/ef-code-first-update-database-encountered-error-there-is-already-an-object-name